# How can i set array of color one by one in Highcharts legend values?

Tags: highcharts

I have to set different colors in pie chart legend values. If I am using static color the color code set in all the legend. but when I set array[0] the colors not to be displayed.

My code:

```
data: [
    {/literal}
        {section name=foo start=1 loop=$value.0.count+1 step=0}
            {assign var=op value=$smarty.section.foo.index}
            {assign var=a value=optcount$op}
            {assign var=an value=optans$op} 
            {assign var=cor value=$colors.col$op}
            {literal}
                {name: '{/literal}{$value.0.$an}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$value.0.$a}{literal}, color: '{/literal}$cor{literal}'}
            {/literal}
            {if $op neq $value.0.count},{/if}
        {/section}
    {literal}
]
```

Here `$colors` is an array, having this value:

```
$colors = array(col1 => '#6B8E23', col2 => '#A9A9A9', col3 => '#696969', col4 => '##FFFFFF', col5 => 'blue');
```

If I pass the value like this, its working but got assigned in all the legends in one color:

```
{literal}
    {name: '{/literal}{$value.0.$an}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$value.0.$a}{literal}, color: '{/literal}green{literal}'}
{/literal}
```

Comment: Legends' color is the same of the related serie. Have you tried to set the serie color ?

Comment: Can u give me the example for this.

Comment: Sure, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/gYpux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                            {foreach from=$value[1] item=foo key=k name=myloop}                             
                            {assign var=op value=$smarty.foreach.myloop.index}                                  
                            {assign var=cor value=$colors.$op}                                  
                            {literal}                               
                            {name: '{/literal}{$k}:{$foo}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$foo}{literal}, color: '{/literal}{$cor}{literal}'}
                            {/literal}  
                            {if $op le $count},{/if}                                
                            {/foreach}
```